# Outlook - how to access appointment attribute COMPANY

Tags: outlook, outlook-object-model, appointment

The Outlook data model for Appointments includes an attribute called COMPANY.  I cannot find where to enter this information anywhere.  If I create a new appointment, I can enter start time, stop time, location, etc.  It appears I cannot enter the data for COMPANY.  Is this accurate?  Why have an attribute which cannot be used?  How do I use it?  Surely I don't have to build a custom Outlook form, do?

Thanks,
GS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the AppointmentItem.Companies Property:

> Returns or sets a String representing the names of the companies
>   associated with the Microsoft Outlook item. This is a free-form text
>   field. Read/write.

This field is not available in the default Appointment form. You would need to customize the existing form or design your own that includes this field.

**You asked:**

> Why have an attribute which cannot be used?

You can use it -- see above.